# Logging GYRO Data via cheap modules or Black Box

Tags: gyro, datalogger, data-storage

I'm trying to figure out a simple solution to log gyro data to use with camera stabilization software.

I know I can use the blackbox from an old flight controller with an external SD card logger, however my issue is how to enable the black box to start logging immediately when powered on?

My other solution would be to use this device along with an external gyro and someonehow log the gyro data?

https://usa.banggood.com/OpenLager-4-Bit-SD-Card-Data-Logger-Interface-Clocked-at-19_2MHz-with-DMA-for-RC-Quadcopter-Flight-Controller-p-1767137.html?cur_warehouse=CN&rmmds=search

https://usa.banggood.com/Geekcreit-6DOF-MPU-6050-3-Axis-Gyro-With-Accelerometer-Sensor-Module-p-80862.html?cur_warehouse=CN&ID=522225&rmmds=search

Comment: Your use of the term "logging", as in save for later analysis, doesn't seem to go well with the purpose of "camera stabilization", as in make the image stable right [now]. Can you clarify this?